# What is wrong with my form?

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm having a problem when I try to save the form's information into the database. My form doesn't seem to be valid, even after manually setting the Theater's id for every theater in the chosen Network.
Here's the related part of my module's **actions.class.php** :

Here's **executeCreate():**

```
public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
    $this->showing = $this->form->getObject();
    $this->processCreateForm($request, $this->form);
    $this->setTemplate('new');
}
```

and now **processCreateForm():**

```
protected function processCreateForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form) {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));

    $form_name = $form->getName();
    $parameters = $request->getParameter($form_name);
    $network_id = $parameters['network_id'];

    $theaters_list = Doctrine_Query::create()
            [...]
            ->execute();

    foreach ($theaters_list as $theater) {
        $form->getObject()->setTheaterId($theater->theater_id);
        $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $showing = $form->save();
        } else {
            foreach ($form->getErrorSchema()->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
                echo '<p>' . $key . ': ' . $error . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
    $this->getUser()->setFlash('update_success', true);
    $this->setTemplate('new');
}
```

Here's the output :

[image: Theater_id required output]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please add your form and your object's schema in your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two strange things going on here which I think break your code.

1. You run the `bind()` method twice which might be resetting your values on the object.
2. I don't think that the `getObject()` method returns the object by reference.

So when you run:

```
    $form->getObject()->setX($val);
    $form->save();
```

then you update the field of the object returned by the form, but then save the original object which is still bound to the form.

Try doing something like this:

```
    $myObject = $form->updateObject()->getObject();
    $myObject->setX($value);
    $myObject->save();
```

The `updateObject()` is important if you use the form to edit an existing object, not to create a new one. Without this you will get the old values of the object.

If you want to run it in a loop you can loop only the setting and saving part. So you would have something like this in your `processCreateForm`:

```
protected function processCreateForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));

    if ($form->isValid()) { //You can check the validity of your form at this point.

        //Create $theatersList
        ...

        $myObject = $form->updateObject();

        foreach ($theatersList as $theater) {
            $myObject->setTheaterId($theater->theater_id);
            $showing = $myObject->save();

            //Do something with $showing

        }
    } else {
         //Print the errors.
    }
}
```

Using this code you can unset the widget for `theatre_id` in your form as it should not be set by the user and does not have to be part of the form validation.

**EDIT**

Some changes to the code:

```
protected function processCreateForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));

    if ($form->isValid()) { //You can check the validity of your form at this point.

        //Create $theatersList
        ...

        $myObject = $form->updateObject();
        $myObjectVars = $myObject->toArray();

        foreach ($theatersList as $theater) {

            $myNewObject = new SomeClass();
            $myNewObject->fromArray($myObjectVars);
            $myNewObject->setTheaterId($theater->theater_id);
            $showing = $myNewObject->save();

            //Do something with $showing

            $myNewObject->free();
            unset($myNewObject);
        }
    } else {
         //Print the errors.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I indeed forgot to unset the `theater_id` widget. I started with this and the form validated. I took your advice and reorganized everything into the `if ($form->isValid()) {}` condition. Thank you. However, the table already has many records and the first newly added tuple has an id of 0, I don't understand why but I guess that's another problem!

Comment: My Showing table has an auto incremented id, which is a hidden field in that form. I now added a list of theaters, making it possible to add a showing for one theater only. This works perfectly using the 2 lines inside the `foreach()` but I still can't seem to make it work for a whole Network. I believe I have to increment the value of the hidden showing id in the `foreach()` too. `$form->getObject()->getId()` only works after a `$showing = $form->save()`. I tried incrementing at the end of `foreach` but I get an error? `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'theater_id' cannot be null`

Comment: Hm... Maybe you should try to create new objects before each save. If I understand your logic correctly you want to fill one form, submit to an action and based on this form create as many rows as theatres you find. See my edits to the answer, maybe this will help.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! Just one thing: `$myObject = $form->updateObject()->getObject()` should be `$myObject = $form->updateObject()`. I had an error using the first : `Unknown record property / related component "object" on "Showing"`.